# MySQL: Convert from Varchar to Date and applying Date_Sub

Tags: mysql, str-to-date, date-sub

I am trying to use 'date-sub' to subtract few month using MySQL.

Before I do that, I figure I have to covert varchar(7) value into date format first.
So, I used following:

```
 select str_to_date('7-2016', '%m-%Y');  -- 2016-07-00 (result)
```

The result was ok, but I am not sure why I get '-00'.

Now, I am trying to apply date_sub:

```
 select date_sub(str_to_date('7-2016', '%m-%Y'), interval 11 month);
```

Why do I get null data?

Comment: *Why do I get null data?* Incorrect datetime literal produces NULL.

Answer (score 1):

> ```sql
> select str_to_date('7-2016', '%m-%Y');  -- 2016-07-00 (result)
> ```

Depends on SQL mode. In general - no. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d4fce697a3833c31f11422a169bb45fd)

---

Use simple

```sql
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1-', @source_literal), '%d-%m-%Y') - INTERVAL 11 MONTH
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f3dc89ed6cf44c3bc18ebc3e97c0c764)

Comment: I tried this: select date_sub(str_to_date(concat('1-', '7-2016'), '%m-%Y'), interval 11 month); but still getting NULL value.

Comment: Oh sorry. I missed the %d. Thank you!